# angular-ui custom build issue

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

In my project I'm using ui.bootstrap.transition, ui.bootstrap.modal ,ui.bootstrap.progressbar, and ui.bootstrap.tabs with custom build from 
their site: http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ and everything working 
properly. But when I added Dropdown I get following error:

```
    Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.21/$injector/modulerr?p0=s4App&p1=%5B%24injector%3Amodulerr%5D%20http%3A%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.2.21%2F%24injector%2Fmodulerr%3Fp0%3Dui.bootstrap%26p1%3D%255B%2524injector%253Amodulerr%255D%2520http%253A%252F%252Ferrors.angularjs.org%252F1.2.21%252F%2524injector%252Fmodulerr%253Fp0%253Dui.bootstrap.dropdown%2526p1%253D%25255B%252524injector%25253Anomod%25255D%252520http%25253A%25252F%25252Ferrors.angularjs.org%25252F1.2.21%25252F%252524injector%25252Fnomod%25253Fp0%25253Dui.bootstrap.dropdown%25250Ay%25252F%25253C%252540http%25253A%25252F%25252Flocalhost%25253A8080%25252Fjs%25252Fangular.min.js%25253A6%25253A450%25250AZc%25252Fb.module%25253C%25252F%25253C%25252Fb%25255Be%25255D%25253C%252540http%25253A%25252F%25252Flocalhost%25253A8080%25252Fjs%25252Fangular.min.js%25253A20%25253A391%25250AZc%25252Fb.module%25253C%25252F%25253C%252540http%25253A%25252F%25252Flocalhost%25253A8080%25252Fjs%25252Fangular.min.js%25253A20%25253A1%25250Ae%25252F%25253C%252540http%25253A%25252F%25252Flocalhost%25253A8080%25252Fjs%25252Fangular.min.js%25253A33%25253A208%25250Aq%252540http%25253A%25252F%25252Flocalhost%25253A8080%25252Fjs%25252Fangular.min.js%25253A7%25253A288%25250Ae%252540http%25253A%25252F%25252Flocalhost%25253A8080%25252Fjs%25252Fangular.min.js%25253A33%25253A148%25250Ae%25252F%25253C%252540http%25253A%25252F%25252Flocalhost%25253A8080%25252Fjs%25252Fangular.min.js%25253A33%25253A225%25250Aq%252540http%25253A%25252F%25252Flocalhost%25253A8080%25252Fjs%25252Fangular.min.js%25253A7%25253A288%25250Ae%252540http%25253A%25252F%25252Flocalhost%25253A8080%25252Fjs%25252Fangular.min.js%25253A33%25253A148%25250Ae%25252F%25253C%252540http%25253A%25252F%25252Flocalhost%25253A8080%25252Fjs%25252Fangular.min.js%25253A33%25253A225%25250Aq%252540http%25253A%25252F%25252Flocalhost%25253A8080%25252Fjs%25252Fangular.min.js%25253A7%25253A288%25250Ae%252540http%25253A%25252F%25252Flocalhost%25253A8080%25252Fjs%25252Fangular.min.js%25253A33%25253A148%25250Agc%252540http%25253A%25252F%25252Flocalhost%25253A8080%25252Fjs%25252Fangular.min.js%25253A36%25253A252%25250A%252540http%25253A%25252F%25252Flocalhost%25253A8080%25252Fjs%25252Fapp.min.js%25253A8%25253A57%25250Am.Callbacks%25252Fj%252540http%25253A%25252F%25252Flocalhost%25253A8080%25252Fjs%25252Fjquery-1.11.1.min.js%25253A2%25253A27239%25250Am.Callbacks%25252Fk.fireWith%252540http%25253A%25252F%25252Flocalhost%25253A8080%25252Fjs%25252Fjquery-1.11.1.min.js%25253A2%25253A28057%25250A.ready%252540http%25253A%25252F%25252Flocalhost%25253A8080%25252Fjs%25252Fjquery-1.11.1.min.js%25253A2%25253A29889%25250AJ%252540http%25253A%25252F%25252Flocalhost%25253A8080%25252Fjs%25252Fjquery-1.11.1.min.js%25253A2%25253A30255%25250A%250Ay%252F%253C%2540http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A8080%252Fjs%252Fangular.min.js%253A6%253A450%250Ae%252F%253C%2540http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A8080%252Fjs%252Fangular.min.js%253A34%253A28%250Aq%2540http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A8080%252Fjs%252Fangular.min.js%253A7%253A288%250Ae%2540http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A8080%252Fjs%252Fangular.min.js%253A33%253A148%250Ae%252F%253C%2540http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A8080%252Fjs%252Fangular.min.js%253A33%253A225%250Aq%2540http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A8080%252Fjs%252Fangular.min.js%253A7%253A288%250Ae%2540http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A8080%252Fjs%252Fangular.min.js%253A33%253A148%250Ae%252F%253C%2540http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A8080%252Fjs%252Fangular.min.js%253A33%253A225%250Aq%2540http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A8080%252Fjs%252Fangular.min.js%253A7%253A288%250Ae%2540http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A8080%252Fjs%252Fangular.min.js%253A33%253A148%250Agc%2540http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A8080%252Fjs%252Fangular.min.js%253A36%253A252%250A%2540http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A8080%252Fjs%252Fapp.min.js%253A8%253A57%250Am.Callbacks%252Fj%2540http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A8080%252Fjs%252Fjquery-1.11.1.min.js%253A2%253A27239%250Am.Callbacks%252Fk.fireWith%2540http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A8080%252Fjs%252Fjquery-1.11.1.min.js%253A2%253A28057%250A.ready%2540http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A8080%252Fjs%252Fjquery-1.11.1.min.js%253A2%253A29889%250AJ%2540http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A8080%252Fjs%252Fjquery-1.11.1.min.js%253A2%253A30255%250A%0Ay%2F%3C%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fjs%2Fangular.min.js%3A6%3A450%0Ae%2F%3C%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fjs%2Fangular.min.js%3A34%3A28%0Aq%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fjs%2Fangular.min.js%3A7%3A288%0Ae%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fjs%2Fangular.min.js%3A33%3A148%0Ae%2F%3C%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fjs%2Fangular.min.js%3A33%3A225%0Aq%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fjs%2Fangular.min.js%3A7%3A288%0Ae%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fjs%2Fangular.min.js%3A33%3A148%0Agc%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fjs%2Fangular.min.js%3A36%3A252%0A%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fjs%2Fapp.min.js%3A8%3A57%0Am.Callbacks%2Fj%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fjs%2Fjquery-1.11.1.min.js%3A2%3A27239%0Am.Callbacks%2Fk.fireWith%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fjs%2Fjquery-1.11.1.min.js%3A2%3A28057%0A.ready%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fjs%2Fjquery-1.11.1.min.js%3A2%3A29889%0AJ%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fjs%2Fjquery-1.11.1.min.js%3A2%3A30255%0A
...gify(arguments[c]):arguments[c]);return Error(a)}}function eb(b){if(null==b||Fa(...
```

Here is link to codepen
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rweHx

How I can solve the problem?

Comment: Can we see your both html/js code?

Comment: From the information I can see, there probably is a dependency error. Please show your config, where you are adding all the modules. The information you provided is very limited so I really cannot help.

Comment: The question is edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quite often I have to answer my questions alone. Pity. I gave up the custom build and download
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/gh-pages/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.10.0.min.js 
Now it works.